how to detect a longPressGesture on a tabItem label
I am unable to figure out how to detect a long press on the label of a tabItem.
Here is some example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Menu")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    print("Long pressed!")
                }
            
            Text("Order")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Order", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
        }
    }
}

In this case I see "Long pressed!" printed only when I long press in the menu view itself. If I move the gesture modifier to Label, I see nothing printed, but instead see this in the debugger when I long press the menu image:

<0x105106690> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out.

How can I do this?
EDIT: I saw this post: Why am I getting this: [SystemGestureGate] <0x102210320> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out with the same debugger message. Apparently it has to do with detecting gestures near the bottom of the screen.

its not possible to add longPressedGesture on a tabItem its its animation detection precedence cannot be changed so the only way is to create your own custom tabview

@MilanLabus that is too bad. Is this documented somewhere in the Apple documentation?

sadly no their documentation can be weak at times I had to contact their developer support when I was trying to do the same

But making your own TabView shouldn't be too hard just maybe difficult to make it look as polished

I will look into it, thanks.
